# Getting a type error when trying to run a basic for loop (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I have what I think is likely a basic question, I'm new to Python but I have searched around but I didn't found any questions similar enough. When I run the below Python code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I'm not really sure why I'm getting this type error, the sentence.labels[0].score code should return a floating point number, but the rest should return a string and Python is telling me that the error is on the "for i in tweets['text'].to_list():" line.

```
sentiment = []
confidence = []

for i in tweets['text'].to_list():
    sentence = flair.data.Sentence(tweets)
    sentiment_model.predict(sentence)
    
    sentiment.append(sentence.labels[0].value)
    confidence.append(sentence.labels[0].score)
    
tweets['sentiment'] = sentiment
tweets['confidence'] = confidence
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks for your time

Comment: so, looks like `tweets` is already a list: `for i in tweets:` should do?

Comment: To answer correctly we need to know what is "tweets". Do print("tweets") and show us the output if it isn't too big.

Answer (score 0):

If *tweets* is a list then you must put in an integer type in *tweets[int]* which is the index of the element in the list.

*'text'* is a string type and a str type cant be used as an index , if you want to do something where *"text"* is present in *tweets* you can try changing it to **tweets[tweets.index("text")]**